# How to show subcategories using loop?

Tags: loops, wordpress, wp-list-categories

i am using `wp_list_categories('child_of=54&title_li=')` method to display all the subcategories, but it is showing only one, how can i use it with loop to show all the subcategories properly.
what should be the changing in the above code.
guide me to the solution

Comment: i am giving solution of my own question, 

`<?php $descendant=array('child_of'=>54)?>
<?php $categories = get_categories($descendant);?>
<?php foreach($categories as $category) :?>
<?php echo $category->name;?>
<?php endforeach;?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am giving solution of my own problem

```
<?php 
    $descendant=array('child_of'=>54);
    $categories = get_categories($descendant);
    foreach($categories as $category) :
        echo $category->name;
    endforeach; 
?>
```